# Safari not displaying HTML5 input data

Tags: html, safari

I am unable to get the HTML5 input data to work in Safari. Does Safari not support HTML5 input data and is there an alternative I can use?

```
 <input type="text" class="knob" data-readonly="true" data-width="120" data-min="0" data-angleoffset="0"
                            data-displayprevious="true" value="85" data-fgcolor="#FFCC00" data-bgcolor="#383838">
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? I see just an input field without a type and with a lot of data- entries.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing type property try this one

Comment: `<input>` fields without a type default to `type="text"` behavior. See the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-input-element.html#the-input-element).